# SVA (SystemVerilog Assertions) : Difference between $assertoff and $assertkill?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

With SystemVerilog Assertions what is the difference between `$assertoff;` and `$assertkill;` ?

They both seem to stop the execution of the assertions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$assertoff` will stop assertions except those already in the active state.

Assertions are active once triggered and waiting to move to failed or completed. `$assertoff` will not stop or **kill** the assertions in the active state.

`$assertkill` will stop all assertions, moving all to state off.

From Cadence Help:

> **$assertoff**
> Suspends checking of all specified assertions until $asserton is encountered. An assertion
> that is already executing, including assertion action blocks, will continue executing.
>
> **$assertkill**
> Halts checking of all specified assertions that are currently executing, then suspends checking of all specified assertions until $asserton is encountered.
> **NB:** *Per the IEEE 1800 SystemVerilog standard, the $assertkill task has no effect on immediate assertions and non-temporal concurrent assertions, due to scheduling issues.*

Answer (score -2):

$assertoff is nothing but it's stops checking all specified assertion unless and untill sunsequent of $assert is on.

While u processing on an assertion it is not to affected whether my assertion is pass or fail.